# Update Parent when Children/Parent change state

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I have a class TourEditor that is children and parent of a tourEditor class that processes the form when submitted. I would like the parent tourEditor to update the compoment object whenever the function updateFiles(files) is called in the children but unfortunately it is only saving the initial state of the children and not updating the state. Any ideas on how can this be solved?

TourEditor.js

```
export default class TourEditor extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {"files": []};
    this.updateFiles = this.updateFiles.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    tourEditor({ component: this });
  }

  updateFiles(files) {
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { tour } = this.props;
    return (<form
      ref={ form => (this.tourEditorForm = form) }
      onSubmit={ event => event.preventDefault() }
    >
      <FormGroup>
       //....
      </FormGroup>
    </form>);
  }
}
```

tourEditor.js

```
export default function tourEditor(options) {
  console.log(options);
  component = options.component;
  validate();
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you call `updateFiles`, you should include it too

Answer (score 1):

I think you need matb33:collection-hooks

This package runs on the server, and allows you to perform actions either before or after database updates. So, for example, you could update the parent when a child record is updated.

Here is an example where I recalculate the number of photos in an album when any of the photos change:

```
var photoUpdate = function(userId,doc) {
    // console.log("Updating photo counts for album "+doc.albumid);
    var photoCount = Photos.find({
        albumid: doc.albumid
    }).count();
    Albums.update({_id: doc.albumid},{
        $set:{
            photoCnt: photoCount
        }
    });
}

Photos.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    photoUpdate(userId,doc);
})

Photos.after.update(function (userId, doc) {
    photoUpdate(userId,doc);
})

Photos.after.remove(function (userId, doc) {
    photoUpdate(userId,doc);
})
```